# Remove key from returned array (using array_filter)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have array_filter functions that returns this:

```php
Array(1) {
  [3]=>
  object(Timber\Term)#5173 (16) {
    ["PostClass"]=>
    string(11) "Timber\Post"
    ["TermClass"]=>
    string(4) "Term"
    ["object_type"]=>
    string(4) "term"
    ["_children"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "Installation Maintenance"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["id"]=>
    int(73)
    ["ID"]=>
    int(73)
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(73)
    ["slug"]=>
    string(24) "installation-maintenance"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(73)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(39)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
    ["term_order"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

What I want is to remove key from array [3](sometimes is different number for key) and get the value.
Tried flattening array but that didn't work, maybe because value is object?

Function that return that array is:

```php
$filter = array_filter($arr, 
  function($item) use ($slug) {
    return $item->slug == $slug;
  }
);
```

### Edit: Trying to clarify what I want to achieve. Srry if I wasn't from the start.

Is it possible to return only object so I can type something like
`$filter->name` and not `$filter[0]->name;`

So this is the data I want:

```php
Object {
  object(Timber\Term)#5173 (16) {
    ["PostClass"]=>
    string(11) "Timber\Post"
    ["TermClass"]=>
    string(4) "Term"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. In general: `unset($someArray[3])`

Comment: Hi! Please can you [edit] your question to show your current code, a sample input, and the output you want? See also the page about producing a [mre] in the [help].

Comment: @Justinas but I don't know which number is used for key. Every time is different.

Comment: Two important things to remember: firstly, we don't know **anything** about your problem other than what you tell us; secondly, it's always important to **break the problem down**. What you need to show us is not _where the data came from_, but _what the data looks like_, and _what you want it to look like_. We also want to see the code you tried that didn't work, because then we can help you understand _why_ it didn't work. It sounds like the `array_filter` isn't actually part of the problem, so _forget it exists_ and show us the part that you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `array_filter` (that always returns array of items), you should just use simple `foreach`.

```
// @lang PHP8

private function findItem(array $items, string $slug): ?\Timber\Term
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->slug === $slug) {
            return $item;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

$item = $this->findItem($items, $someSlug);

echo $item->slug ?? throw new \Exception("No item found with slug '{$slug}'");
```